# Unable to add objects inside kivy layout regisered as a factory widget

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Ive been trying to add a couple of widgets inside a BoxLayout which is regisered as a factory object,

So this what my code looks like

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory 

kv='''

# THIS is object 1 which will be added to main grid

<object_1@BoxLayout>:

    orientation:'vertical'
    size_hint_y:None
    adaptive_height: True
    height:self.minimum_height 
    id:obj_1
    
    Button:
        size_hint:None,None 
        on_press:app.add2()
        
# this is object_2 which i want to be added into
object_1 

<object_2@BoxLayout>:

    orientation:'vertical'
    size_hint_y:None
    adaptive_height: True
    height:self.minimum_height
    id:obj_2

#main grid

BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    size_hint_y:None
    adaptive_height: True
    height:self.minimum_height 
                        
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size_hint_y:None 
        adaptive_height:True
        height:self.minimum_height 
        id:sc_grid          
        Button:
            size_hint:None,None 
            on_press:
                app.add_1()                     

'''

class MyApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
    
    def add_1(self):
        self.root.ids.sc_grid.add_widget(Factory.object_1())
        
MyApp().run()
```

In the above code object_1 is added to main grid when button is pressed ,

I need to add object_2 inside object_1 how can i do it ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] as well as the error stack trace.

Comment: @john Anderson I've updated it with more code you can check it out now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to call a method in the `App`, you can just do the `add_widget()` in the `kv`. You must include:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
```

in your `kv` in order to use `Factory` in your `kv`. Then you can replace:

```
on_press:app.add2()
```

with:

```
on_press: root.add_widget(Factory.object_2())
```

Here is a modified version of your `kv` that uses the above approach:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
# THIS is object 1 which will be added to main grid

<object_1@BoxLayout>:

    orientation:'vertical'
    size_hint_y:None
    adaptive_height: True
    height:self.minimum_height 
    id:obj_1

    Button:
        text: 'Add 2'
        size_hint:None,None 
        on_press: root.add_widget(Factory.object_2())

# this is object_2 which i want to be added into object_1 

<object_2@BoxLayout>:

    orientation:'vertical'
    size_hint_y:None
    adaptive_height: True
    height:self.minimum_height
    id:obj_2
    Label:
        text: 'Object 2'
        color: 0,0,0,1
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.texture_size

#main grid

BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    size_hint_y:None
    adaptive_height: True
    height:self.minimum_height 

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size_hint_y:None 
        adaptive_height:True
        height:self.minimum_height 
        id:sc_grid          
        Button:
            size_hint:None,None 
            text: 'Add 1'
            on_press:
                app.add_1()
```

I have added a few minor changes (like a `Label` in `object_2`) to make it easier to see the results.

Also, although this code works, your class names should start with an upper case letter. Not following that suggestion can actually cause errors in your `kv`.

Comment: Actually i tried to call it from app because i had  backend algorithms which should also be executed on press , anyway I'll try to execute that portion through the sub widget (object_2)

Comment: You can do it through a method in the `App`, but you will need to pass the `object_1` object to the method. Otherwise, there is no way to know which `object_1` is being added to. Something like: `on_press:app.add2(root)`, then the method in the `App` would be defined like this: `def add2(self, object_1_instance):`

Comment: I'll check that out